# Power shell script to search for a file and replace strings in that file

Tags: string, powershell, replace, directory, scripting

The script recurses through this folder and looks for a file named “test”
If it finds a file named “test”, it looks in that file for an email address (test@email.com)

If it finds `test@email.com`, it changes this string to `itworks@email.com`
Writes a message saying `“test" changed in [folder name]”` (where [folder name] is the name of the path where it found the "test" file)

I've tried this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ‘C:\SCRIPT TEST ’ –Recurse| 
Foreach-Object { Rename-Item $_.FullName ($_.FullName -replace "test@email.com","itworks@email.com ")}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your file have an extension (test.txt, test.xml etc), otherwise replace -filter "test.*" by -filter "test"

Solution 1 :

```
#take only file where filename = test into your directory
Get-ChildItem "C:\SCRIPT TEST" -file -Recurse -filter "test.*" | %{

    #get content of file
    $content=get-content $_.FullName -raw
    
    #if content have email searched, replace email and save into file
    if ($content -clike "*test@email.com*")
    {
        $PathFile=$_.FullName
        $content.Replace('test@email.com', 'itworks@email.com') | Set-Content $PathFile
    
        "Test changed into the file '{0}'" -f $PathFile
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2 :

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -file -recurse -filter "test.*" | Select-String -Pattern 'test@email.com' -SimpleMatch -list | %{

$Path=$_.Path
$Content=(get-content $Path -raw).Replace('test@email.com', 'itworks@email.com')
$Content | Set-Content $Path -PassThru | %{"Test changed into the file '{0}'" -f $Path}

}
```